# Terminate a pipeline if no data flows for n seconds

Tags: pipe, timeout

I have a piece of software that produces data on stdout for a while, then continues running but doesn't output any more data.

I have a pipeline that takes that output and processes it further, saving the output in a file. However, because the original process keeps running after it finishes producing output, I have to terminate this manually. Is there a command that will kill the running program once it hasn't produced any output for some number of seconds?

I know about the timeout command, but that looks like it operates on a fixed timeout. I don't have a reliable way of determining how long the software will keep outputting for.

Example:

Suppose I have `generate-data` that looks like this and cannot be modified. In reality, this is a piece of compiled software that I would prefer not to modify.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

for x in {1..5}; do
    echo $x
    sleep 1
done

while true; do sleep 1; done
```

I currently run something like `./generate_data | grep '[2-4]' > output`, which produces the output I want but doesn't ever terminate.

I would like to terminate the pipeline once `generate_data` doesn't output anything for 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use the read command. The -t switch is your friend.
Similar this

```bsh
(echo "we:re:e";sleep 2;echo "d:dd:d") | while read -d ":" -t 2 a;do echo $a;done
```

The output:

```
 we
 re
```

```bsh
(echo "we:re:e";sleep 1;echo "d:dd:d") | while read -d ":" -t 2 a;do echo $a;done
```

The output:

```
we
re
e d
dd
```